# Merge columns together if the other values are blank

Tags: python, pandas

I tend to routinely get data files which have a lot of similar columns, but for each row only one of those columns actually has any data. Though sometimes it only looks that way. Ideally what I want to do is have a function that I can input a list of columns to check, and for any rows that contain just 1 value have a row that combines those columns together and change that column to NaN so I can easily remove the excess columns at the end. If multiple columns have data than don't merge/change for that row.

So for example I have this DF

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
               "id": pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5,6,7]),
               "a1": pd.Series(['a',np.NaN,np.NaN,'c','d',np.NaN, np.NaN]), 
               "a2": ([np.NaN,'b','c',np.NaN,'d','e', np.NaN]), 
               "a3": ([np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN, 'f'])
               })
```

code wise right now I have this

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np    
def test(row, index, combined):
    values = 0
    foundix = 0
    #check which if any column has data
    for ix in index:
        if not (pd.isnull(row[ix])):
            values = values + 1
            foundix = ix
    #check that it found only 1 value, if so clean up
    if (values == 1):
        row[combined] = row[foundix]
        for ix in index:
            row[ix] = np.NaN
    return row

df["a"] = np.NaN
df.apply(lambda x: test(x, ["a1", "a2", "a3"], "a"), 1)
print df
```

So problem I have with my code is

1. I get the feeling this is the wrong direction to go to solve my problem
2. I don't fully understand how to get my apply function to actually apply to the row to change it.

my ideal output would be (mainly to help clean up the data afterwards and deal with the weird cases):

```
   a1   a2   a3   id  a
0  NaN  NaN  NaN   1  a
1  NaN  NaN  NaN   2  b
2  NaN  NaN  NaN   3  c
3  NaN  NaN  NaN   4  c
4    d    d  NaN   5  NaN
5  NaN  NaN  NaN   6  e
6  NaN  NaN  NaN   7  f
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My method seems marginally quicker:

```
In [415]:

df = pd.DataFrame({
               "id": pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5,6,7]),
               "a1": pd.Series(['a',np.NaN,np.NaN,'c','d',np.NaN, np.NaN]), 
               "a2": ([np.NaN,'b','c',np.NaN,'d','e', np.NaN]), 
               "a3": ([np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN, 'f'])
               })
df
Out[415]:
    a1   a2   a3  id
0    a  NaN  NaN   1
1  NaN    b  NaN   2
2  NaN    c  NaN   3
3    c  NaN  NaN   4
4    d    d  NaN   5
5  NaN    e  NaN   6
6  NaN  NaN    f   7

[7 rows x 4 columns]
In [416]:

def gen_col(x):
    if len(x.dropna()) > 1:
        return NaN
    else:
        return x.dropna().values.max()

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np    
def test(row, index, combined):
    values = 0
    foundix = 0
    #check which if any column has data
    for ix in index:
        if not (pd.isnull(row[ix])):
            values = values + 1
            foundix = ix
    #check that it found only 1 value, if so clean up
    if (values == 1):
        row[combined] = row[foundix]
        for ix in index:
            row[ix] = np.NaN
    return row
%timeit df.apply(lambda x: test(x, ["a1", "a2", "a3"], "a"), 1)
%timeit df['a'] = df[['a1','a2','a3']].apply(lambda row: gen_col(row), axis=1)
df
100 loops, best of 3: 7.08 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 3.24 ms per loop
Out[416]:
    a1   a2   a3  id    a
0    a  NaN  NaN   1    a
1  NaN    b  NaN   2    b
2  NaN    c  NaN   3    c
3    c  NaN  NaN   4    c
4    d    d  NaN   5  NaN
5  NaN    e  NaN   6    e
6  NaN  NaN    f   7    f

[7 rows x 5 columns]
```

The key thing I am doing here is to check the number of values after dropping all `NaN` values, this seems quicker than your code